# How to add a vector in reverse order with another vector in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

There is a vector `vector<int>v`
I want to add another vector `vector<int>temp` in reverse order with this vector.

For example,

```
   v = {1, 5, 7} and

temp = {11, 9, 8}
```

I want to add temp in reverse order, that is `{8, 9, 11}` to vector `v`.

So that, `v` will be : `v = {1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11}`

Here's how i did it :

```
int a[] = {1, 5, 7};
vector<int>v(a,a+3);
int b[] = {11, 9, 8};
vector<int>temp(b,b+3);

for(int i=temp.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
  v.push_back(temp[i]);

for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
  cout<<v[i]<<" ";
cout<<"\n";
```

Is there a built in function in STL or C++ to do this ? or do i have to do it manually ?

Comment: `temp (v.rbegin(), v.rend())` reverse iterators FTW

Answer (score 9):

Use reverse iterators:

```c++
std::vector<int> temp(v.rbegin(), v.rend());
```

Or `std::reverse_copy()`:

```c++
std::reverse_copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(temp));
```

Answer (score 7):

Try the following

```
v.insert( v.end(), temp.rbegin(), temp.rend() );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 5, 7 };
    std::vector<int> v( a, a + 3 );
    int b[] = { 11, 9, 8 };
    std::vector<int> temp( b, b + 3 );

    v.insert( v.end(), temp.rbegin(), temp.rend() );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 5 7 8 9 11
```

Comment: Works on my machine (using g++ -std=c++11. Thank you. Note: the other example works as well, but I had to include <algorithm> to compile it. Your example uses only one method to copy (i.e. vector::insert), which is compatible with my particular style requirement.